# Testing Exception Messages with Shouldly

Tags: c#, exception, shouldly

Is there a way to test the exception messages with shouldly?

An example:

```
public class MyException: Exception{
}
```

The method  to be tested:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        throw new MyException("Message");
    }
}
```

I would usually test this in this way:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        new ClassUnderTest().DoSomething();
        Assert.Fail("Exception not thrown");
    } catch(MyException me)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("Message", me.Message);
    }catch(Exception e)
       Assert.Fail("Wrong exception thrown");
    }
}
```

With shouldly I can now test if a exception is thrown:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestWithShouldly()
{
    Should.ThrowException<MyException>(() => new ClassUnderTest().DoSomething());
}
```

But how can I test the message of the exception?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The `Should.Throw()` method returns the exception, so you can continue to test if for other things.

For example:

```
Should.Throw<MyException>(() => new ClassUnderTest().DoSomething())
    .Message.ShouldBe("My Custom Message");
```

Or, if you want to do more than just test the message:

```
MyException ex = Should.Throw<MyException>(() => new ClassUnderTest().DoSomething());
```

You can then do what you like with `ex`.

**Note**: Shouldly V2 uses `Should.ThrowException<>()`

Comment: Damn, so simple. Should have figured it out myself. Thank you

Comment: Apparently, in latest versions it should be `Throw<MyException>`

Comment: What do you do if your Action takes a ref and can't be used in a lambda?

> Cannot use ref local inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression