# Is there some Assert method which can be used for unit test on whether a method throws an exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert

In C#, I have a method which throws an exception when a certain condition is true. I am supposed to write a unit test method to verify that.

Since the method being tested doesn't return a boolean value, I can't use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.IsTrue` method. Which assert method can I use? Thanks.

Comment: @sasha_gud Yes, but those answers are horribly out of date

Comment: If you're open to using an assertion library, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543708/testing-exception-messages-with-shouldly

Answer (score 0):

Use `Assert.Throws`, like so:

```
var ex = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => My.Method(null));
Assert.Equals("foo", ex.ParamName);
```

This works in XUnit and in the later versions of MSTest (install MSTest as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/) to get up-to-date versions)

Comment: Thanks. Are MSTest and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools` separate from each other?

Comment: @Tim MSTest used to be (still is) shipped with Visual Studio -
the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools` assemblies that come with Visual Studio is the older version of MSTest (that doesn't include the `Assert.Throws` methods). Newer versions of Visual Studio reference the NuGet package when you create a test project, rather than those assemblies.