# Unit test doesn't complete, the method being tested just throws an exception. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm currently in the process of working through a Unit Testing in C# course - specifically for NUnit (I'm using NUnit 3.8.1 with NUnit3TestAdapter 3.1.13).

My issue in question, is that when I'm testing for an exception to be thrown, my debugger stops & throws an exception on the method that I'm testing. I'm not sure if I'm mistaken with the behaviour, but I can't see what I've done wrong.

Firstly - I've read up on the [documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws) & can't see a problem.

I've also looked through various other posts on stack overflow that just don't seem to quite point at the answer, as none of these solutions have worked for me.

[Is there some Assert method which can be used for unit test on whether a method throws an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316606/is-there-some-assert-method-which-can-be-used-for-unit-test-on-whether-a-method)

[C# Unit Testing - Test method throwing NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958118/c-sharp-unit-testing-test-method-throwing-nullreferenceexception)

[Why, when I am testing that a method throws an exception and the method throw an exception, does the test stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384572/why-when-i-am-testing-that-a-method-throws-an-exception-and-the-method-throw-an)

The class I'm testing is as follows (and was provided from the instructor on the course - they have demonstrated that this works).

```cs
using System;

namespace TestNinja.Fundamentals
{
    public class ErrorLogger
    {
        public string LastError { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler<Guid> ErrorLogged; 

        public void Log(string error)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            LastError = error; 

            // Write the log to a storage
            // ...

            ErrorLogged?.Invoke(this, Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, my test methods -

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using TestNinja.Fundamentals;

namespace TestNinja.UnitTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ErrorLoggerTests
    {
        //private ErrorLogger _errorLogger;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            //_errorLogger = new ErrorLogger();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Log_WhenCalled_SetTheLastErrorProperty()
        {
            var logger = new ErrorLogger();

            logger.Log("a");

            Assert.That(logger.LastError, Is.EqualTo("a"));
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(null)]
        [TestCase("")]
        [TestCase(" ")]
        public void Log_InvalidError_ThrowArgumentNullException(string error)
        {
            var logger = new ErrorLogger();
            Assert.That(() => logger.Log(error), Throws.ArgumentNullException);
        }
    }
}
```

The test I'm talking about is `Log_InvalidError_ThrowArgumentNullException`. On each test case the code breaks on the line `throw new ArgumentNullException();` in `ErrorLogger`. I have to close the box & continue running the code.

When I run this test individually, the test runs to completion, however when I run all, that's where the exception is thrown & my testing is stopped.

Originally, my unit testing had the `SetUp` method uncommented & I was using that private field, however I swapped over to a fresh instance to make sure there weren't any issues with lingering objects.

Comment: You could try `Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => logger.Log(error));`, but I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing. Are you running the tests as debug? Are you sure you don't have a break-point hanging out on that line? What exception are you getting when the tests fail?

Comment: Yes, I'm running them in debug. The keyboard shortcut for run all tests is set to `Ctrl R, A` but run all tests in debug is `Ctrl R, Ctrl A`. I just double checked them. I've used the run all tests button to confirm. You've solved the problem of my own stupidity.

Comment: Those are the best solutions: they require 0 code changes.

Comment: @JonathonChase Do you think this question is worth leaving up? I'm not sure if anyone else is likely to be as daft as I've been! Or should I just let the mods decide?

Comment: Nobody is voting to close, and at least one person has made the mistake. These things happen.